# building function/method dynamically using string in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) with 3 columns. The 2 last columns (word1 & word2) are dynamically created (based on a user input earlier in the code):

```
**Title  word1  word2**
 tl1      er     fg 
 tl2
 tl3     ghj    
 tl4            hjk
 tl5     dfg     gh
 tl6     dfk
 tl7
 ...
```

Now what I want to do is to delete all rows where both word1 and word2 are empty, so in the example above I would end up with:

```
**Title  word1  word2**
 tl1      er     fg 
 tl3     ghj    
 tl4            hjk
 tl5     dfg     gh
 tl6     dfk
 ...
```

As the columns are generated dynamically I dont know the name of them. However what I do know is that they are generated from a list (which again is generated via a user input).
The list looks like this: `wordList = ['word1','word2']` (but they could also be 'word10' & 'word21' based on the user input)

So in order to delete the empty rows I can use these two lines:

```
indexNames = df[(df['word1'] == '') & (df['word2'] == '')].index
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

However as I dont know the names of the columns I try to do some dynamic stuff like this:

```
columnString=""
for word in wordList:
    if (columnString == ""):
        columnString = "(df['" + word + "'] == '')"
    else:
        columnString =  columnString + " & (df['" + word + "'] == '')"
```

when I then do: `print(columnString)`

I get: `(df['word1'] == '') & (df['word2'] == '')`

So from here I guess it would be possible to do below (taking advantage of not actually knowing the column names):

```
indexNames = df[columnString].index
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

The result should be exactly the same as below (that works perfectly, but is not dynamic):

```
indexNames = df[(df['word1'] == '') & (df['word2'] == '')].index
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

However with the version composed with the string I get a keyerror:

```
KeyError: "(df['skal'] == '') & (df['sap'] == '')"
```

I come from C# where such manipulation/dynamic creation of operations is pretty straight forward. I guess it is also possible to do this in Python, but how ?

Comment: What you want to achieve seems to be a job for *evil* `eval()`, but there seems to be better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two variables, say `name1` and `name2` instead of hardcoded strings `'word1'` and `'word2'`. The variables `name1` and `name2` can take any string value you wish.

```
name1 = 'word1'
name2 = 'word2'
indexNames = df[(df[name1] == '') & (df[name2] == '')].index
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

---

Or, starting from a `list`, say `names`:

```
def multi_bitwise_and(items):
    iter_items = iter(items)
    result = next(iter_items)
    for item in iter_items:
        result = result & item
    return result


indexNames = df[multi_bitwise_and((df[name] == '') for name in names)].index
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to create a *boolean mask* then use [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) along `axis=1` on this mask to create another boolean mask `m` where truthy values corresponds to the condition where all values in columns in `wordList` along a given row is `empty`, then use this mask to filter the dataframe:

```
wordList = ['word1', 'word2']
m = df[wordList].eq('').all(axis=1)
df = df[~m]
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
  Title word1 word2
0   tl1    er    fg
2   tl3   ghj      
3   tl4         hjk
4   tl5   dfg    gh
5   tl6   dfk
```

Comment: Excellent Shubham!, This solution is simple, works like a charm, and fast enough for my use case. Thanks :)

Comment: @Sand20 If this answered your question you may upvote and accept the answer.